# if $n^2 + 2016n$ is equal to a square number, how would i find the largest value of n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Q: $n^2 + 2016n$ is equal to a square number. What is the largest value of n for which this is true, giving the answer as a remainder when divided by 1000.The answer is a whole number and is a number from 1-999.

I'm not sure if my answer is correct. I factorised n out giving $n(n+2016)$ and then I said that $(n+2016)=na^2$ where a is a number.

Then $n(1-a^2)=2^5.3^2.7$

$n(1-a)(1+a)=2^5.3^2.7$

So then wouldn't the largest number for n be when $(1-a)(1+a)=2^0.3$

then the answer = $2^5.3.7$ Is that correct?

Comment: Hint: $n^2+2016n+(1008)^2$ is also a square.

Comment: What do you mean "giving the answer a remainder when divided by 1000"?

Comment: The last 3 digits probably

Comment: @fleablood. See the comment on your comment from vicky era.

Comment: You seem to have assumed that if $n(n+2016)=b^2$ then $n$ divides $b,$ that is, $b=na,$ which is not a valid move. ... You also have $n(1-a^2)=2016.$ That should read $n (a^2-1)=2016.$

Comment: @user254665  ?????????????  "See the comment on your comment from vicky era"?????   Why on earth do you feel I haven't seen that comment and why do you feel the need to post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

$n^2 + 2016n = M^2$

$n^2 + 2016n + 1008^2 - M^2 = 1008^2 = 2^8*3^4*7^2$

$(n-M + 1008)(n+M + 1008) = 2^8*3^4*7^2$

Let $(n-M + 1008) = 2^a3^b7^c$ and $(n+M + 1008) = 2^{8-a}3^{4-b}7^{2-c}$

So $2n + 2016 = 2^a3^b7^c + 2^{8-a}3^{4-b}7^{2-c}$

So we need to maximize $n = \frac{2^a3^b7^c + 2^{8-a}3^{4-b}7^{2-c}}2 - 1008 \le 999$

Or $2^a3^b7^c + 2^{8-a}3^{4-b}7^{2-c} \le 4014$

Not entirely sure how to maximize to such a range.  Picking values at random I get $16*81*7 + 16*7 = 16*7(82)=9184$

So $n = 3584$

And $(3584)^2 + 2016(3584) = 4480^2$.

But that's too big.

I'm not sure why they are restricting to $n < 1000$.  The true largest would be  $n = (2^7*3^4*7^2 + 2)/2 - 1008 =  253009$

With $(253009) + 2016(253009) = 254015^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. $$n^2 + 2016n = \left(n^2 + 2016n + \left(\frac{2016}{2}\right)^2\right) - (1008)^2$$
2. $$a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = (a + b)^2$$
3. $$a^2 - b^2 = \left(a + b\right)\left(a - b\right)$$

*Can you take it from here?*